Access Denied Error when Connecting Node.js App to MySQL RDS Instance
I'm working on a Node.js application using mysql2/promise to connect to an Amazon RDS MySQL instance. Despite having correct credentials and network configurations, I'm encountering an Access denied error. Here are the details:
Error Message:
Error: Access denied for user 'db_user'@'my.ip.address' (using password: YES)

Connection Code:
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT
});

Environment Variables:
DB_HOST=mydatabase.example.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER=db_user
DB_PASSWORD=hidden_password
DB_NAME=my_database

Security Groups: Configured to allow my local IP address.
I've verified the credentials and user privileges but still face this issue. Any insights or suggestions?
A bit more info of what I've tried as well:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON admin.* TO 'db_user'@'my.ip.address';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

While connected to the RDS instance locally through the workbench.
That resulted in Access Denied
This is just a sample of one of my Express routes:
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const authenticateToken = require('./middleware/authenticateToken.cjs');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
  });

// Handling connection establishment
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Database connection error:', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Database connection established');
    connection.release(); // Release the connection back to the pool
  });

router.get('/get-locations', authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const [results] = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM location');
    res.status(200).json(results);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching locations:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error fetching locations');
  }
});


The problem is that this is not really a programming issue. Your node.js code does connect to mysql server, but gets rejecteddue to lack of access rights. The usual sources of error are: incorrect user name or password, incorrect access rights, or you are connecting to the wrong mysql instance. We can't really tell which one of the above you need to fix, but none of the above are programming problems.

Btw, granting all access to a mysql server to an app service account is a very bad idea!

@Shadow - everything works locally (when the db is local as well) - it is just connecting to the AWS RDS - it doesnt' like something.

Note that user@localhost and user@<ip-address> are effectively two different users to MySQL. They might have different privileges, and even different passwords.

@BillKarwin - When I log in to the mysql workbench I'm using the username/password combo and the database works fine.  But when I use the same username/password in my Node/Express application (pointing to the RDS instance) I get the error.

Again, there is nothing wrong with your database connection, it's your access rights that or credentials are not ok in mysql.

@Shadow - I agree it appears to be access rights.  Any suggestions on what I need to look for on that?

Erm, grant those access rights tp the mysql user for your app that it needs. I really do not know what access rights your app needs.
